# how to cluster users based on tags

Tags: machine-learning, neo4j, apache-pig, classification, hierarchical-clustering

I'd like to cluster users based on the categories or tags of shows they watch.  What's the easiest/best algorithm to do this?

Assuming I have around 20,000 tags and several million watch events I can use as signals, is there an algorithm I can implement using say pig/hadoop/mortar or perhaps on neo4j?

In terms of data I have users, programs they've watched, and the tags that a program has (usually around 10 tags per program).

I would like to expect at the end k number of clusters (maybe a dozen?) or broad buckets which I can use to classify and group my users into buckets and also gain some insight about how they would be divided - with a set of tags representing each cluster.

I've seen some posts out there suggesting a hierarchical algorithm, but not sure how one would calculate "distance" in that case.  Would that be a distance between two users, or between a user and a set of tags, etc..

Comment: Did you see: http://gist.neo4j.org/?8173017 "Movie Recommendations with k-Nearest Neighbors and Cosine Similarity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to **cluster the users** according to their tags.

To keep it simple, assume that you only have 10 tags (instead of 20,000 ones). Assume that a user, say user_34, has the 2nd and 7th tag. For this clustering task, user_34 can be represented as a **point** in the **10-dimensional space**, and his corresponding coordinates are: [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0].

In your own case, each user can be similarly represented as a point in a 20,000-dimensional space. 
You can use [Apache Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/) which contains many effective clustering algorithms, such as K-means.

Since everything is well defined in a mathematical coordinate system, computing the distance between any two users is easy! It can be computed using any distance function, but the Euclidean distance is the de-facto standard.

**Note:** Mahout and many other data-mining programs support many formats suitable for SPARSE features, i.e. You do not need to insert **...,0,0,0,0,...** in the file, but only need to specify which tags are selected. (See  [RandomAccessSparseVector in Mahout.](http://search-lucene.com/jd/mahout/math/org/apache/mahout/math/RandomAccessSparseVector.html))

**Note:** I assumed you only want to cluster your users. Extracting representative info from clusters is somewhat tricky. For example, for each cluster you may select the tags that are more common between the users of the cluster. Alternatively, you may use concepts from *information theory*, such as **information gain** to find out which tags contain more information about the cluster.

Comment: is k-means good with binary data?  it seems like the distance calculations would be a bit strange with such 0s and 1s.  Is the Jaccard distance better than euclidian in this case?

Comment: k-means is very simple, but yet effective and fast (It has O(n.k) complexity (n=#instances=#users, k=#features=#tags)). Average-linkage hierarchical clustering usually results in better solutions, but have O(n^2.k) complexity. There exist some advanced methods that are specifically crafted for clustering sparse datasets, but I think they have no implementation in famous software packages.

Euclidean distance is not that bad in practice, but you may use cosine distance, which is more friendly with sparse data. (You only need to count the intersection and union of the tags for the two users).

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `neo4j`. You can model your data using the following node labels and relationship types.

*If you are not familiar with neo4j's Cypher language notation, `(:Foo)` represents a node with the label `Foo`, and `[:BAR]` represents a relationship with the type `BAR`. The arrows around a relationship indicate its directionality. neo4j efficiently traverses relationships in both directions.*

```
(:Cluster) -[:INCLUDES_TAG]-> (:Tag) <-[:HAS_TAG]- (:Program) <-[:WATCHED]- (:User)
```

You'd have `k` `Cluster` nodes, 20K `Tag` nodes, and several million `WATCHED` relationships.

With this model, starting with any given `Cluster` node, you can efficiently find all its related tags, programs, and users.

Comment: so that would get me the nodes and relationships, but how would I do a k-means or calculate initial cluster nodes with neo4j?

Comment: I don't suggest using k-means. That requires you to have a `k` in mind already, which is very hard to determine and will be an arbitrary number that you come up with. Use hierarchical instead; this will begin with each object in its own cluster and iteratively join objects into clusters until there is one super-cluster. How these objects are joined at each step depends on the similarity measure you choose to use and the join criteria (single, complete, average, etc.). You can then look at the cubic clustering criterion (calculated at each step) to determine the optimal number of clusters.

Comment: Where is your data stored?

Comment: I have the data locally and can also put it on amazon s3

Comment: Is it in a db, in csv, or other?

Comment: it's in both db, csv, graph... I've converted it to several different repositories