# Feature column contains list - how to parse to k-means algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to parse my data to sklearn.cluster.KMeans. Here is an example showing my data:

```
import sklearn.cluster
import numpy as np

d = {'ID' : pd.Series([1, 2, 1]), 
     'X1' : pd.Series([111, 222, 333]),
     'X2' : pd.Series([[0,1], [1,2], [2,4]]),
     'X3' : pd.Series([111, 222, 333])
    }

df1 = (pd.DataFrame(d))

labels = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    labels.append(row['ID'])

print(df1)

   ID   X1  X2      X3
0   1  111  [0, 1]  111
1   2  222  [1, 2]  222
2   1  333  [2, 4]  333

print(labels)

[1, 2, 1]
```

This is how I tried to extract the data into features:

```
features = np.array([x[1:] for x in df1])
clust_centers = 2
model = sklearn.cluster.k_means(features, clust_centers)
```

This returns the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: D
```

**The question:**

How can I use this data format as input to k-means?

```
    ID X1   X2      X3
0   1  111  [0, 1]  111
1   2  222  [1, 2]  222
2   1  333  [2, 4]  333
```

What about this format? Can this be used as input?

```
    ID X1   X2          X3
0   1  111  [0:3, 1:4]  111
1   2  222  [1:2, 2:3]  222
2   1  333  [2:2, 4:2]  333
```

**Edit - more information about the feature types**

The dataset is a extract of the bitcoin transactional network.

Label:

**id(int**) - this was a 160 bit Hash. i.e. a bitcoin address which I have converted to a integer id value.

Features:

*numerical*

**value(float)**: amount of bitcoins sent or received in the transaction

**pagerank(float)**: pagerank of the transaction

**in-degree(float)**: in-degree of the node in the transaction

**out-degree(float)**: out-degree of the node in the transaction

*categorical*

**tags(int) in a list**: tags represent one of six categories (gambling, services, finance etc..), can be either represented as string or integer. I am aggregating tags, hence the list representation.

**Sample Row**

`ROW   ID    PAGERANK IN_DEGREE OUT-DEGREE  VALUE  IN_TAG  OUT_TAG
767   7504  1.500    2         1           0.0012  [1, 2]  [1,5]`

The goal here is to predict the category a new user is likely to interact with.

much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the output of `print(features)`.  You're taking the all but the first character from each column name as your features, which isn't what I think you're intending to do.  I think you want `features = df1.values[:, 1:]` instead.  That will still give you an error when you try to do the clustering, but it's an error due to having a list within your data, which is really what your question is trying to get at.

Comment: your right, thats not what i am intending to do. i suppose what i am looking for is a list of `ids` as labels (which i have), and then to generate my `sample x features` matrix for k-means input. - i assume this is the correct input for k-means

Comment: KMeans only works for Euclidean distances. What's the distance between elements in `X2`?

Comment: `X2` features are categorical values. I have converted tags to integer representations

Comment: That just means you assigned arbitrary numbers to them. It doesn't make them actual numbers. You still cannot calculate the Euclidean distance between them.

Comment: @user3939059 ayhan is correct. You should consider whether KMeans is the right algorithm for you in this case. The fact that it will output clusters (once you get the list issue out of the way), does not mean that these clusters are correct in any way.

Comment: @user3939059 see [here](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data).

Comment: thanks for the reply, i will take a look at alternative solutions. would 'one hot encoding' help at all with this problem and k-means?

Comment: I was just looking at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943391/how-to-cluster-users-based-on-tags and if I understand correctly I could represent the tagged data as binary values in a n dimensional space?

Comment: can you give some more information about your data? e.g. what does each column represent, at least whether these are categorical, nominal, or some measure. Best in actual domain terms. In general you should normalize all features [for KMeans to work properly](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21226/126849)